# How am I able to use SQL code to store information in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

So in this code, the entire database is called GProperty, and I need to access the table called ScannedDocs. If the filename already exists I need to do nothing. 'filename' is the variable of the read in file while 'fileName' is a field in ScannedDocs that stores new filenames in the database. If there is no file that exists I need to give it an id which is why I search for the biggest id and then add 1 to ensure I give the new file a new id. 
I just need a few pointers to make sure I'm doing this correctly. Any help is appreciated. Thank You!!

```
        GProperty db = new Gproperty();

        List<int> args = (from ScannedDocs in db.ScannedDocs
                          where filename = fileName
                          select *).ToList(); 

        if (args.Count() = 0)
        {
            int i = select MAX(id) from db.ScannedDocs;
            db.ScannedDocs.id = i+1;
```

Comment: You may not need to get 'i' for every piece of data.  If you are a single user to the database get i once max work.  If you have a multi-user database then you have to worry about multiple user simultaneously try to write the next i.  So then you have a stored procedure in database get the next i and make sure only one user call the next i method.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which database you're operating on, there should be a way to auto-increment to the max ID from a given table at the moment of an insert. For instance: [IDENTITY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) on MS SQL Server and MySQL. For Oracle, you can use [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm).

Comment: this, possibly in combination with auto-increment should fulfill OP's needs.

Comment: Any advice for SQLite? Plus I know I'm not quer-ing the id correctly. Any help on how I could format that correctly?

Comment: @Anon SQLite has a column property called [AUTOINCREMENT](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). You shouldn't need to query your max ID from your C# code. Just make you don't inform an ID in your insert command, and the database will provide it for you.